# Idiomatic usage of filter, map, build-list and local functions in Racket/Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

I'm working through [Exercise 21.2.3](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-27.html#node_sec_21.2) of HtDP on my own and was wondering if this is idiomatic usage of the various functions. This is what I have so far:

```
(define-struct ir (name price))
(define list-of-toys (list
                      (make-ir 'doll 10)
                      (make-ir 'robot 15)
                      (make-ir 'ty 21)
                      (make-ir 'cube 9)))

;; helper function
(define (price< p toy)
  (cond
    [(< (ir-price toy) p) toy]
    [else empty]))

(define (eliminate-exp ua lot)
  (cond
    [(empty? lot) empty]
    [else
     (filter ir? (map price< (build-list (length lot)
                                         (local ((define (f x) ua)) f)) lot))]))
```

To my novice eyes, that seems pretty ugly because I have to define a local function to get `build-list` to work, since `map` requires two lists of equal length. Can this be improved for readability? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement `eliminate-exp` with `filter` alone:

```
(define (eliminate-exp ua lot)
  (define (price< toy) (< (ir-price toy) ua))
  (filter price< lot))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It would appear that lambda is useful in this case, but HtDP doesn't introduce it until later in the curriculum (Section 24).

Comment: @Greenhorn I updated the answer so that it does not directly make use of the `lambda` form.

Comment: that's a good answer, thanks. It's much more elegant but I need to turn on the advanced features on Racket to have your example work. Interesting enough, `filter` gets called first then `map`, while in my example the order is reversed. I shall learn from this.

Comment: After you're allowed to use lambda, I think you'll find that's the most idiomatic way to do it. It's very common to see `filter' or `map' take a procedure that is used one-off only for this purpose. In which case it's very convenient -- and readable -- to define it "inline" as an anonymous function using lambda, instead of defining it with a name elsewhere.

Comment: P.S. My previous comment was @Greenhorn.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what build-list is or does, but surely you can just do:

```
(lambda (x) ua)
```

instead of:

```
(local ((define (f x) ua)) f)
```